# Open Modal Dialog box on top of parent page from an Iframe

Tags: asp.net, popup

Here I am again seeking your advice and guidance.

Say I have a a widget application that the general public use by inserting the script on their websites. This script will then open an Iframe and the application will run within this Iframe.

So far, I never came close to discover a way to open a modal dialog (not a pop up, but the floating div that appears 'on top' while blacken/fading the background) on top of the Parents page. What I ended up with is having the modal dialog opening within the Iframe only.

Short of doing a regular Window.open .. is there any other way to achieve this?

(I am using ASP.NET with Ms Ajax and also JQuery)

Cheers and thank you in advance,
Lasker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should re-evaluate what you are trying to do. Instead of using an IFrame, have the script communicate with your server side code via AJAX, and render directly to the page.